# How can I get values of each key index (first level) and work with it to do something

Tags: python, api, dictionary

How can I done this task working with Dict in Python.

I have this dict:

```
dict = {
    "id1": {
        "var0": "id1_value_var0", 
        "var1": "id1_value_var1", 
        "var2": "id1_value_var2", 
        "var3": "id1_value_var3", 
        "var4": "id1_value_var4", 
        "var5": "id1_value_var5"
    }, 
    "id2": {
        "var0": "id2_value_var0", 
        "var1": "id2_value_var1, 
        "var2": "id2_value_var2, 
        "var3": "id2_value_var3", 
        "var4": "id2_value_var4", 
        "var5": "id2_value_var5"
    } 
}
```

I am trying to go through each first level key to pick up its values 
​​to do something and then move on to the second key.

Example: for first_level_key in dict

```
       get this result of id1 (Key of first level)     
       {'var5': id1_value_var5', 'var4': 'id1_value_var4', 'var1': 'id1_value_var1', 'var0': 'id1_value_var0', 'var3': 'id1_value_var3', 'var2': 'id1_value_var2'}

       get value of var1, var2, var4, var5

       [Send to my API  when this done go to my next key of first level:

       get this result of id2(Key of first level)
       {'var5': id2_value_var5', 'var4': 'id2_value_var4', 'var1': 'id2_value_var1', 'var0': 'id2_value_var0', 'var3': 'id2_value_var3', 'var2': 'id2_value_var2'}         

       get value of var1, var2, var4, var5

       [Send to my API  when this done go to my next key of first level and so one.....
```

This is the code for the API but it is not here I have problems:

```
#for i in var_list_items:
#    headers = {
#        'Content-type': 'application/json',
#        'Authorization': 'Token 5f6e918b4b3b9121bd8e0f7dce17fe7d5cd870e7'
#    }
#    data = {
#        "olt_hostname": "xxxxxxxx", 
#        "olt_tipo": "Nokia", 
#        "port": str(i[0]), 
#        "vlan_id": str(i[1]), 
#        "mac": str(i[2]), 
#        "fdb_id": str(i[3]), 
#        "vmac": str(i[5]), 
#        "user": "user01", 
#        "ont_admin_satus": "DOWN", 
#        "uni_admin_satus": "DOWN", 
#        "uni_oper_status": "DOWN", 
#        "fecha_dato_modificacion": strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#    }
#    response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.121:8000/OrangeLab/api_orangelab_new/', headers=headers, json=data)
```

I would be very grateful that someone can help me with this issue that took a couple of hours and I don't get it ....

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the following article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As your question is currently formatted, I am not sure what you are asking and will have to flag it unless it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to find a way to do it and I want to share it in case someone is interested in the same problem:

for k, v in dict.iteritems():
        print k, v
        for x in v.iteritems():
            print x[1]
            print type(x)
            if x[0] == 'var0':
                print ("I found var0")
                data['mac'] = x[1]   <-- Preparing or filling another dict what will be sent to the API.

Comment: I believe `.iteritems()` is deprecated, no? Also, the formatting of your code is off.